# ValueError: Shapes (None, 14065, 17) and (None, 17) are incompatible

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensor, deep-residual-networks

I am trying to train the model below with Indian Pines dataset but I get the following error

## Model:

```
    def ResNet50(input_shape, classes=16):

    # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape
    #X_input = Input(shape=(97,145,200))
    X_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Zero-Padding
    X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3), data_format='channels_last')(X_input)  # 3 x 3 padding

    # Stage 1 (≈4 lines)
    X = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2))(X)
    print('==================', X.shape)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    print('BN', X.shape)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    print('relu', X.shape)
    X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1))(X)
    print('max', X.shape)

    # Stage 2 (≈3 lines)
    X = convolutional_block(X, f=3, filters=[64, 64, 256], s=1)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [64, 64, 256])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [64, 64, 256])

    # Stage 3 (≈4 lines)
    X = convolutional_block(X, f=3, filters=[128, 128, 512], s=2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512])

    # Stage 4 (≈6 lines)
    X = convolutional_block(X, f=3, filters=[256, 256, 1024], s=2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024])

    # Stage 5 (≈3 lines)
    X = convolutional_block(X, f=3, filters=[512, 512, 2048], s=2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [512, 512, 2048])
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [512, 512, 2048])

    # AVG-POOL (≈1 line). Use "X = AveragePooling2D(...)(X)"
    X = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(X)

    # output layer
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(17, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    print("=================",X.shape)
    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name='ResNet50')
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

## Identity Block

```
def identity_block(X, f, filters):
# Retrieve filters
F1, F2, F3 = filters

# Copy of the input
X_shortcut = X

# First layer
X = Conv2D(F1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# Second layer
X = Conv2D(F2, kernel_size=(f, f), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# Third Layer
X = Conv2D(F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)

# Last step: Adding shortcut value to F(x), and pass it through a RELU activation
X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
X = Activation('relu')(X)

return X
```

## Convolutional Block

```
    def convolutional_block(X, f, filters, s):
    # Retrieve filters
    F1, F2, F3 = filters

    # Copy of the input
    X_shortcut = X

    # First layer
    X = Conv2D(F1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(s, s), padding='valid')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Second layer
    X = Conv2D(F2, kernel_size=(f, f), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Third Layer
    X = Conv2D(F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)

    # Shortcut path
    X_shortcut = Conv2D(F3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(s, s), padding='valid')(X_shortcut)
    X_shortcut = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X_shortcut)

    # Last step: Adding shortcut value to F(x), and pass it through a RELU activation
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    return X
```

## Main:

```
 def load_hsi():
    X = loadmat('dataset/Indian_pines_corrected.mat')['indian_pines_corrected']
    y = loadmat('dataset/Indian_pines_gt.mat')['indian_pines_gt']
    print(f"X shape: {X.shape}\ny shape: {y.shape}")
    print("===========================================")
    return X, y



    X, y = load_hsi()


    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    y_train = y_train.transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(-1, y_train.shape[2])

    y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
    y_test = y_test.transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(-1, y_test.shape[2])


    #ADD one dimension to X_train so it becomes 4D

    X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0)
    X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=0)

    y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=0)
    y_test = np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=0)

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

I get the following error:
File "C:\Users-\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py",
line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 14065, 17) and (None, 17) are incompatible
```

I think my data is the wrong size, if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong

#Model summary

```
Model: "ResNet50"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 97, 145, 20  0           []                               
                                0)]                                                               
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 103, 151, 20  0          ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                0)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 49, 73, 64)   627264      ['zero_padding2d[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (BatchNorm  (None, 49, 73, 64)  256         ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
 alization)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)        (None, 49, 73, 64)   0           ['batch_normalization[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 47, 71, 64)   0           ['activation[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 47, 71, 64)   4160        ['max_pooling2d[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_1 (BatchNo  (None, 47, 71, 64)  256         ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
 rmalization)  

                                                                               
.....
 activation_45 (Activation)     (None, 6, 9, 2048)   0           ['add_14[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_50 (Conv2D)             (None, 6, 9, 512)    1049088     ['activation_45[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_50 (BatchN  (None, 6, 9, 512)   2048        ['conv2d_50[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 activation_46 (Activation)     (None, 6, 9, 512)    0           ['batch_normalization_50[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_51 (Conv2D)             (None, 6, 9, 512)    2359808     ['activation_46[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_51 (BatchN  (None, 6, 9, 512)   2048        ['conv2d_51[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 activation_47 (Activation)     (None, 6, 9, 512)    0           ['batch_normalization_51[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_52 (Conv2D)             (None, 6, 9, 2048)   1050624     ['activation_47[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_52 (BatchN  (None, 6, 9, 2048)  8192        ['conv2d_52[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 add_15 (Add)                   (None, 6, 9, 2048)   0           ['batch_normalization_52[0][0]', 
                                                                  'activation_45[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_48 (Activation)     (None, 6, 9, 2048)   0           ['add_15[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 average_pooling2d (AveragePool  (None, 3, 5, 2048)  0           ['activation_48[0][0]']          
 ing2D)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 30720)        0           ['average_pooling2d[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 17)           522257      ['flatten[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,727,761
Trainable params: 24,674,641
Non-trainable params: 53,120
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you show the model summary? It's easier to check, but I have a suspicion that your flattening isn't working as expected. The error is coming from the last Dense layer

Comment: Hi! I put the first part and the last part of the model summary was too big to add it all

Comment: Thank you, can you also add your x and y shapes?

Comment: Sure, here they are:
 X_train shape: (1, 97, 145, 200)
y_train shape: (1, 14065, 17)

Comment: and X shape before train_test_split is: (145,145,200) and y is: (145, 145)

Answer (score 0):

So the **main** issue is that the shape of your labels is `(1, 14065, 17)`, whereas your model outputs `(None, 17)`. Also if you have 16 classes you need 16 units on the last dense layer **not** 17.

For the labels, there is no need to add a dimension for the channel. They are labels, meaning either indexes, or one-hot-encodings, therefore the correct shape is `(14065, 17)` and not `(1, 14065, 17)`.

**Another** issue is how your images are shaped. For your images, the dimension needs to be `(n_images, dim1, dim2, n_channels)`, where `n_images` is the number of images, `dim1` and `dim2` are the dimensions of each image and `n_channels` is the number of channels of each image.

EDIT:

*"Yes that is the size of my X (145,145,200) that is what X.shape shows me after i load the data"*

Then you simply do `np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)` or `X.reshape((1, 145, 145, 200))` to have `(1, 145, 145, 200)`

Comment: well 200 is the channels number and the 1 is from dimension extension because the model take 4D as an input and if i have X_train shape (1,97,145,200) and y_train shape (97,145,17) with the same output from the model (None,17) it gives me the following error
 ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 97
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: An image does not have 200 channels. Max is 3, for the RGB values. You are mistaking something in the data which is leading you to reshaping your data incorrectly. The error you now get is because, as I pointed out, the 1 in the X_train_shape is being interpreted as the number of samples in the data.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using a hyperspectral image the (Indian Pines dataset) and this image has 200 channels

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes more sense, then what is the point of expanding the dimension? Your data should look like (n_images, dim1, dim2, n_channels), where dim1xdim2 are the dimensions of the image

Comment: You need to know the size of the images and then we can go from there

Comment: The original image size is 145*145 but im not sure how many images i have i think 1 for each channel

Comment: That's not how images work. One single image, either has 1 or more channels, if the size is 145 then the X needs to be (n_images, 145, 145, 200), IF you indeed have 200 channels. Hyperspectral images have 4 to 20 color channels, not 200

Comment: Yes that is the size of my X (145,145,200) that is what X.shape shows me after i load the data

Comment: Check the edit please